# What can't be done in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm preparing a quick presentation on the possibilities of Powershell management in Windows 2012R2, versus GUI-based administration. Now, I'm trying to pin down what administrative tasks typically performed using MMCs or similar are still not possible using Powershell cmdlets/functions.

Some examples of functionality that is at least almost completely managable using Powershell as of 2012R2 is IIS, DHCP, Active Directory. I'm well aware that there are many additional possibilities using pre-powershell tooling, WMI, COM or the .NET assemblies, but in my experience very few sysadmins feel comfortable going there, so I'm limiting the scope to the cmdlets.

Comment: This is not a good question for serverfault.  This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  We expect questions to be mostly aimed at asking about a specific problem.

Comment: I would say that asking what functionality is not included is a quite clear question? Can I phrase it in a clearer way?

Comment: I think a proper answer as the question currently is phrased would comprise a bookshelf or three. As PS can access the .NET API you might just as well ask 'what can't be accomplished programmatically in .NET?'

Comment: I still can't open vi on my FreeBSD box with PowerShell.

Comment: The number of (new) cmdlets is not so much dependent on the PowerShell version but more on the Windows (Server) version. 2012 and again 2012 R2 have many additional cmdlets over 2008 R2. Considering you can call other cli tools, .net classes, COM,  WMI and the Win32 API from PowerShell there is not much you can not do, but there are still things you can't do with 'native' cmdlets.

Comment: @carlpett, the problem isn't clarity.  The problem is that there your question is could and probably will solicit a bunch of worthless answers.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that POSH is Turing-complete, so I guess the only answer is "solve the halting problem."

Comment: Sigh. How about being constructive? Instead of trying to find the worst possible question from my phrasing? What I'm asking about is what cmdlet support is missing. I'll rephrase and hope.

Comment: What you can or can't do in PS could fill several books... and not surprisingly, many books have been written on the topic.  If you narrow your question scope a bit, you might transform it into an answerable question, but as it stands now, this just isn't a good question.  There are over 250 on a default Windows 7 (PSv2) install.  You want a list of them?  [Click here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714569.aspx)  Even the most generous interpretation of your question (what's new in PSv4) didn't get you the answer you wanted, so work on determining what you actually want to ask.

Answer (score 8):

Your question as it stands does not make sense

## PowerShell is not just a bunch of `cmdlets`!

PowerShell is a powerful and extensible management tool - anything you can do from a Management Console, you can do from PowerShell - it's simply a matter of familiarity with the underlying APIs

Even configuration options that doesn't necessarily conform to well-known APIs can be manipulated through PowerShell, through builtin storage providers for the filesystem, the registry, the certificate store etc.

### WMI

Interacting with WMI through PowerShell is almost to easy, at least looking back at my early attempts at VBScript (oh, the horrors).

The core modules in PowerShell comes with a variety of cmdlets, including `Get-WMIObject` ([Windows 2012 introduces the more generic `CIM cmdlets`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets.aspx) like `Get-CimInstance`):

```
$OSbitness = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
```

Holy balls?! We just used WMI to tell us the OS architecture without invoking `wmic` or writing 700 lines of wsh error handling!

### COM

PowerShell can invoke and interact with COM applications. Many Microsoft applications can be accessed this way, using the `New-Object` cmdlet.
See for instance [this example of creating and saving a spreadsheet using Excel](http://www.petri.co.il/export-to-excel-with-powershell.htm) - pretty neat!

### .NET? No problem!

Since .NET is already and integral part of PowerShell (same object model, derived type system, same runtime environment etc.), .NET extensibility is right at your fingertips using a mash of reflection and a few builtin cmdlets like `New-Object` and `Add-Type`. Extend away!

The Powershell runtime collection types are not for you? You want a HashSet of strings? No problem:

```
$myHashSet = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.Hashset[String]
```

Need to import existing vendor libraries to your Powershell session? No problem:

```
Add-Type -Path C:\Stupid\Old\App\Lib.Helper.dll
```

Need a managed library from the GAC? No problem:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
or 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

How about some managed code on the fly? A few static functions that were easily implemented using `C#`? No problem:

```
$typeDef = "public class HelperFuncs {public static string HelloWorld(){return "Hello World";}}"
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeDef
[HelperFuncs]::HelloWorld()
```

### Native APIs?

To access the native APIs in Windows we'll have to go through a bit of .NET wrapping, or marshalling, but [DllImport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532712/using-dllimport-to-load-unmanged-dll-into-manged-application) and [PInvoke.NET](http://www.pinvoke.net/) makes [this task trivial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/25/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1.aspx) as well:

```
$MethodDefinition = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool CopyFile(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, bool bFailIfExists);
'@
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Kernel32' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

$Kernel32::CopyFile("C:\somefile.txt","C:\newLocation\somefile.txt")
```

---

Add to the above, that PowerShell is its own scripting language, building on the best of many worlds including syntax borrowed from proven languages like Perl, ksh, Tcl and of course C# and its ancestors.

It has flow control options like loops, switches, if-else and a wide variety of generic comparison operators, support for multi-value assignment and an incredibly powerful object-oriented pipeline, and a myriad of other features.

To be honest, the only real limitation to PowerShell with regards to Windows Server management is sitting 20" from the screen

Comment: I think you gave him a perfect answer. Now he knows that almost everything is possible with Powershell.

Comment: As a Linux/Bash guy, this *is* making me a little jealous.

Comment: @Ladadadada Mission accomplished :D

Comment: @Ladadadada  Well, you can take solace in telling yourself that PowerShell still has to manipulate *Windows* on the backend, and Windows is inferior to *nix, after all.  Of course, saying that won't make it true, or change the fact that Windows guys finally have the superior CLI... but it might make you feel a little better. :)

Comment: You know what I like about POSH? No "xargs" and no (or at least less) munging text in a pipeline - you're just passing objects.